# How to configure julia, R, C, C++, Fortran, python in jupyter lab?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to setup a Lab environment for Machine Learning Course. I want to use jupyterLab with python, R, C, julia, and Fortran. I also want to know the best way to setup all these, in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have installed julia and jupyter lab. When I run jupyterlab, the kernel option menu does not show other than python. How to make others (R, julia..) also available?

Answer (score 0):

For Julia to work in jupyter(lab), you must install the [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) package. Open the Julia REPL and type

```
] add IJulia
```

This should generate the necessary kernel specifications and Julia should show up in jupyter(lab) afterwards.

Similarily, I believe that you need to install [IRKernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) to get R working.

With regards to C and Fortran, note that those are static languages while jupyter is primarily an interface for interactive languages like **JU**lia, **PY**thon, and **R** (add a **TE** and you get **JUPYTER**, which isn't a coincidence). I know that there have been attempts to use jupyter with C++ but you generally shouldn't expect it to be as simple to setup and use (if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

There is already a Fortran kernel for Jupyter developed here,

https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/jupyter-CAF-kernel

which amazingly supports [Coarray parallel programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGSoCvTLfkw) features of the Fortran standard.